# Android Wear 2.0 Settings List Items

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I am trying to replicate the menu lists in the settings app on Android Wear 2.0:

[image: Settings Example]

Since `WearableListView` is now deprecated, the recommended way to make lists is to use `wearablerecyclerview`. How can I attach a menu XML resource to a recylerview, and how can I mimic the design of the settings example and include a header?

Comment: As for the title, I think you'll find it trivial to add one when you've got your PreferenceFragment set up.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!